# Issue with updating text within a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update the text within a div. The div is draggable and resizable (using jquery ui plugin). I need to update the text without affecting any of these properties set to the div.

On making a div resizable, jquery plugin adds two inner divs and this divs are getting removed on updating the text of the parent div using .text() method. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Structure of the div before updating

```
<div ondblclick="showPopup(this)" class="draggable ui-draggable ui-resizable" 
             id="Text10" style="position: relative;">
    test
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" 
         style="z-index: 1001;"></div></div>
```

Structure of the div after updating

```
<div ondblclick="showPopup(this)" class="draggable ui-draggable ui-resizable"     
             id="Text10" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;">
    test-updated
</div>
```

Script used:

```
$('#Text10').text($('#newText').val());
```

Comment: yes all your html, inside the div will be removed, if you want to update only text `test` use a container like `<span>` or '<p>' and change the context inside it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be to add a span tag in the outer div. The text change can then be performed with:

```
$('#Text10 > span').text($('#newText').val());
```

Comment: Oops. Missed that. Whatever. I learned something new. Thanks alot. This is it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using inner span element http://jsfiddle.net/4P73F/

JavaScript:

```
var i = 0;
$('#foo').draggable();
$('#foo').resizable();
setInterval(function () {
    $('#innerText').text('Some text ' + i);
    i += 1;
}, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #ccc"><span id="innerText"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mgechev. Issue got fixed while using span within the div. Thanks for answering.